# Diferent result between query and application (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have this scenario:

I have this query:

```
SELECT min(id) 
  FROM ( SELECT c.id
              , id_Cliente 
           FROM creditos AS c
          INNER JOIN  creditos_ren AS r 
                  ON r.id = (SELECT rr.id 
                               FROM creditos_ren AS rr 
                              WHERE rr.id_credito= c.id 
                                AND rr.cancelado=false 
                                AND rr.fecha_vto>='2018-07-15' 
                                AND rr.fecha_vto<'2018-07-24' 
                              ORDER BY rr.fecha_vto  
                              LIMIT 1 
                            )      
          LEFT JOIN  creditos_ren AS rx 
                 ON rx.id =(SELECT xx.id 
                              FROM creditos_ren AS xx 
                             WHERE xx.id_credito=c.id 
                               AND xx.id != r.id 
                               AND xx.fecha_vto >= r.fecha_vto  
                               AND xx.cancelado=false 
                             ORDER BY xx.fecha_vto 
                             LIMIT 1
                           )  
          WHERE c.id NOT IN ( SELECT d.id_credito 
                                FROM campanas_instancia_lineas AS d
                            ) 
            AND c.gestion_local = 0 
            AND c.enumerador IN ('CR_NORMAL','CR_ENTREGADO','CR_NUEVO','CR_MOROSO') 
          ORDER BY r.fecha_vto
                 , c.total_vencido desc
                 , rx.fecha_vto 
        ) AS p 
 GROUP BY id_Cliente;
```

When run the query in the WorkBench, the result for example are 260 matches.

But, when I run the same query in the application the result are 497 matches.

I use javaEE with nativeQuery.

I try to use VIEWs, with the same result

If someone help me, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The last subselect `SELECT d.id_credito FROM campanas_instancia_lineas d` look somehow incomplete.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far?

Comment: Hi, I try to execute query part by part and every time all is ok. I try to rewrite the query, and same result in DB, but the nativeQuery result is different. I don't know what else to do. Thanks for your help

Comment: what happens with the query in Workbench if you comment both "LIMIT 1"

Comment: Do that give me an error, because subquery return more than one results

Comment: The `WHERE c.id NOT IN (SELECT d.id_credito FROM campanas_instancia_lineas AS d)` must be replaced with `FROM ... LEFT JOIN campanas_instancia_lineas AS d ON c.id = d.id_credito ... WHERE d.id_credito IS NULL`. Or at least with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM campanas_instancia_lineas AS d WHERE d.id_credito = c.id)`.

Comment: @Kondybas *The last subselect ... look somehow incomplete* Why? It's a common check a value not exists in another table.

Comment: *in the WorkBench ... 260 matches ... in the application ... 497 matches* Enable General log and compare queries texts obtained by MySQL from Workbench and from application. The difference is a reason. If not, check Workbench settings/options for a query result limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both approaches are looking the same `DATABASE`.

Further debugging:

1. Turn on the general log.
2. Run the query both ways.
3. Turn off the general log.
4. Compare the two queries; there must be something different.
5. Figure out what is changing what.

Meanwhile, these indexes may help performance:

```
creditos_ren:  INDEX(id_credito, canceladom fecha_vto, id)
creditos:      INDEX(gestion_local, enumerador)
```

What table is `id_Cliente` in?

Comment: Hi Rick, I did it, it's the same query in the same order. Both with two different result. I'm really lost here.
Thanks for the suggestion, I put the indexes.
The id_cliente comes from Clientes table.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have one DataBase

Comment: @AlejandroFerreira - But the table `Clientes` is not mentioned in the query???